# Proof of $a\mid b\ \wedge\ b\mid a\ \Rightarrow a=\pm b$ for integer numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this proof for divisibility over integer numbers:
$$a\mid b\ \wedge\ b\mid a\ \Rightarrow a=\pm b$$
*Proof.*:
Hypothesis: $a\times d=b$, $b\times e=a$. Hence
\begin{align}a \times (d\times e)&=^{\langle {\rm Associativity}\ \times \rangle}
\\[0.1cm]&=(a\times d)\times e=^{\langle {\rm Hyp.}:\ a\times d=b\rangle}\\[0.1cm]&=b\times e=^{\langle {\rm Hyp.:}\ b\times e=a\rangle}\\[0.1cm]&=a\end{align}

I understand almost the entire proof, but I don't where the $a * (d*e)$ expression comes from.

Comment: What do "Dem" and "Hip" stand for?

Comment: The $a*d*e$ expression come so, from nowhere. He starts from this expression and the simplifies it. It does not follow from something, if this is what you mean.

Comment: @JimmyR. Dem ~ Demonstration, Hip. ~ Hypothesis

Comment: @JimmyR., I have changed them. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $x\mid y\implies |x|\leq |y|$, so you have,$$a\mid b~\land~b\mid a\implies |a|\leq |b|~\land~|b|\leq |a|\implies |a|=|b|$$

Comment: @learner This is only true if either $y\neq 0$ or $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @user236182: otoh, that's also the conclusion; there's no other way $|a|=|b|$ could be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a starting point; in effect, the proof is basically saying that since $a * (d * e) = a$, then $d * e = 1$ and the only possible values for them are either $d=e=1$ or $d=e=-1$. This in turn shows that $a = \pm b$, given the definitions of $d$ and $e$.

Let's formulate the entire proof in complete sentences, to make it easier to grasp:

**Theorem:** If $a$ and $b$ divide each-other evenly, then $a=\pm b$.

**Proof:**

1. Let $d$ and $e$ be the respective results of evenly dividing $a/b$ and vice versa, i.e. $a = b*d$, $b = a * e$.
2. Next, consider the product $a * (d * e)$. Since $a*(d*e)=a$ (as shown in the question), then we must have $d*e=1$.
3. $d*e=1$ implies that $d=e=\pm 1$, since there are no other numbers that would multiply to $1$.
4. In step 1. we defined $a=b*d$, which with $d=\pm 1$ proves the theorem.